# NODE.js/javascript проверка пустой ли файл

Tags: javascript, node.js

Существует ли для этого уже готовая функция? Если нет, то как можно её написать. Спасибо!

Comment: А откуда у вас файл?

Comment: файл лежит на сервере, перед записью в него нужно узнать пустой он или нет, от этого зависит что с ним делать.

Comment: fs.stat или statSync https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback

Answer (score 1):

```
var buf = new Buffer(1024);

fs.open('input.txt', 'r+', function(err, fd) {
   if (err) {
       return console.error(err);
   }    

fs.read(fd, buf, 0, 1024, 0, function(err, bytes){
          if (bytes == 0){
             console.log("File is empty");
          }
})
})
```

Comment: я так понимаю files.length это проверка пуста ли директория.  А пуст ли файл?

Comment: @AlexeyAntonovich предупреждать надо где фаил проверять...

Comment: @AlexeyAntonovich изменнил.. Можно так...

Comment: @C.Raf.T для информации о файле есть fs.stat